# Display .bin depth image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, bin

Here is the .bin [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gcsb07n05u9vtlm/test0.bin?dl=0) which I saved in c#. Please anyone help to view this in MATLAB. the dimension of image 424 x 512.

I have tried this code, but its not working correctly

```
file = fopen('test0.bin', 'r');
A = fread(file, 424*512, 'uint16=>uint16');
A1 = reshape(A, 424, 512);
imagesc(A1)
```

Before doing downmark please tell me the reason so j can update this

Comment: What is not working correct? How did you save it in C#? Are you aware of the difference between row major and column major programming languages?

Comment: No i am not aware of row major and col major.. I can not see the image correctly.. I used the sample code found at stack overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [row major and column major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) programming languages. To simplify, which is the second element in memory? First column second row or second column first row? There is no "right" answer, thus there are programming languages using the one or the other. This is the major problem in your case. If you make an error here, the image looks like the one you got.

To fix the problem with row and column major, you have to use:

```
A1 = reshape(A, 512, 424).';
```

This swaps rows and columns to get a row-major behaviour, then transposes to turn the image right.

Comment: It is working well.. I have an color [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xu95thcii9msnh8/color1.bin?dl=0) with dim of `1920 x 1080`, I used same method for that, but its again not working

Comment: With that little information I can't give a useful answer. Please create a new question where you include the code for writing and reading, the written file and what image you expect.